# Capturar IP Real do usuário

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Como faço para capturar o IP real/IP Público do usuário que está acessando a aplicação? O IP do computador eu consigo capturar normalmente, mas quero saber o IP público desse cliente.

Answer (score 5):

[Isto é uma variável acessível em qualquer *Action*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Ou então:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Comment: Esse código retorna o IP Local da máquina e não o IP de internet dela. Tanto que se vc acessar http://www.meuip.com.br e criar uma aplicação com o código informado, verá que os dois ip's diferentes.

Comment: @ZackMorgan Mas o objetivo é pegar o IP de quem está acessando minha aplicação. Não o meu IP público.

Comment: Esse IP da aplicação de nada me serve em um processo de auditoria judicial. Pois veja bem, minha máquina pode ter o IP 10.10.1.20 em minha rede. Mas também, numa outra rede de um vizinho, ele também pode ter o mesmo IP. Então, com o IP Real, caso haja necessidade, eu entro em contato com o provedor, ele me diz as informações necessárias e consequentemente, se toma as medidas necessárias. Na minha aplicação eu capturo já o IP do computador, que é totalmente "inútil" pra mim.

Comment: @ZackMorgan Não é o IP do computador. É o IP **remoto** do **cliente**, no caso, quem está acessando sua aplicação. A documentação deixa isso bem claro.

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, faço isso do lado do cliente. Via javascript, pois quem faz a requisição javascript a algum serviço que fornece o IP real é o cliente. Pois preciso desse tipo de IP. Dessa forma, seto uma variável que envia pro meu controller esse IP, e também capturo esse IP remoto. Se é a melhor forma eu não, mas que deu certo, deu.

Comment: Acho um pouco trabalhosa demais esta forma, mas admito que funciona.

Answer (score 5):

Eu pego assim:

```
        public static string GetPublicIP()
        {
            string url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org";
            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            string[] a = response.Split(':');
            string a2 = a[1].Substring(1);
            string[] a3 = a2.Split('<');
            string a4 = a3[0];
            return a4;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

adicione o using

```
using System.Net;
```

inclua o código abaixo

```
string host = Dns.GetHostName();
string ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[2].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

tenta usar isso

```
<?php

    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] 
        ?? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] # when behind cloudflare
        ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'] 
        ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
        ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'] 
        ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
        ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
        ?? '0.0.0.0';
    
    # Earlier than PHP7
    $clientIP = '0.0.0.0';
    
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
        # when behind cloudflare
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']; 
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    
    echo "Meu cliente IP: ". $clientIP;
```